# Is Microsoft Edge the replacement for IE, or just an alternative browser?

Tags: internet-explorer

I need to decide whether I should test for both IE and Microsoft Edge when creating websites.  If IE is end-of-life, has been superseded by Edge, has a limited support horizon, and IE users are being pushed to switch, it is a different situation than if both browsers are actively supported and promoted, and Edge and IE are just alternative browsers.

I'm not asking for opinions on what testing I should do.  I just need a little clarification as to what's going on with IE and what role Edge has.

Comment: MS is trying to replace IE with Edge, and has stated that their goal is for EdgeHTML to be equivalent to Chrome's Blink as far as web-standards support goes. The reality of the current situation however, is that both browsers are in fairly wide usage (IE still has more market share than Edge, but Edge is at a respectable 4.3% as of last month) and for now, both should probably be tested, however since (I can't remember where I read it, but) MS has stated that 'any differences between the way Chrome renders a page and the way Edge renders it is a bug', theoretically you could skip testing Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Edge is not as HTML5 compliant as Chrome or Opera, as per [HTML5TEST.COM](https://html5test.com/results/desktop.html) , and is virtually tied for third place with Firefox. Only Safari of the major modern browsers is less compliant. So, no.

Comment: I'm thinking I should test my code using Edge still since they are trying to create hype around it. Do you agree? Also, why is Edge in that list of browsers and not IE?

Comment: @Daniel - Question seeking our opinion on a subject like that is out of scope here at Superuser

Comment: The phrases "IE" and "standards compliant" are best not used in the same article; hence IE's absence.  And, https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ may be a more fruitful place to pose your question.

Comment: The fact that HTML5 compliant is less doesn't mean that Edge isn't a replacement for IE. It's definitely a built-in replacement from MS's perspective. MS just hasn't been able to keep up with standard compliance